# Unable to locate a specific package under Debian GNU / Linux 8.7

Tags: linux, list, debian, deb, neovim

I want to install [Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim) but I get the following error:

```
~ » sudo apt-get install neovim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package neovim
```

My sources.list:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

Uname:

```
Linux myserver 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 (2016-02-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Lsb_Release:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:        8.7
Codename:       jessie
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

well it's unable to locate the package cause there is no neovim in Debian stable as far I know. There is one in the testing repository.

Answer (score 1):

Neovim is available in Testing (Stretch) so it should be available to Stable (Jessie) by using Backports.

General idea here: https://backports.debian.org/

Method here: https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

For jessie add this line

> deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main

to your sources.list (or add a new file with the ".list" extension to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/) You can also find a list of other mirrors at https://www.debian.org/mirror/list

Run apt-get update

Then

> apt-get -t jessie-backports install neovim